# Cannot get the content of the docx file by the export link

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I successfully got an export link for the docx file with Google Drive API. But when I was requesting content by this link I got the error:

> Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.
> To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our help center.
> We're sorry for the inconvenience.
> The Google Docs Team

I can load content for almost all documents in this way except several ones. What can cause this error?

**GET request (with export link):**

```
/export/bhaesec4g5rmhivrvn5o52thks/1ca9c1mv3vebpavoq02qk8dnns/1710944805000/105250506097979753968/106060929513419285720/<doc_id>?id=<doc_id>&exportFormat=docx&dat=...
```

**GET response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 (850ms)
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://docs.google.com
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2024 14:26:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-chromium-appcache-fallback-override: disallow-fallback
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Expires,Pragma,Server,X-Google-GFE-Backend-Request-Cost
Content-Security-Policy: require-trusted-types-for 'script';report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/docs-tt
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://docs.google.com
Content-Security-Policy: base-uri 'self';object-src 'none';report-uri https://doc-0g-7s-docstext.googleusercontent.com/document/cspreport;script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-KHS_si0487i-8LC4i7rJ6A' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval';worker-src 'self' blob:
Referrer-Policy: origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
x-l2-request-path: l2-managed-5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//docs.google.com/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Product+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" nonce="SNZIuIYhKP-y-W6MOr10TA"><style nonce="SNZIuIYhKP-y-W6MOr10TA">.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png);-webkit-background-size:116px 41px;background-size:116px 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:"Product Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url(//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png)}}sentinel2879</style><style type="text/css" nonce="SNZIuIYhKP-y-W6MOr10TA">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}</style><style type="text/css" nonce="SNZIuIYhKP-y-W6MOr10TA">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style></head><body><div id="outerContainer"><div id="innerContainer"><div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;"><div style="margin: 18px 0; position: absolute; white-space: nowrap;"><a href="//support.google.com/docs/"><img height="35px" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/product/docs_lockup2.png" alt="Google logo"/></a></div></div><p style="padding-top: 15px">Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes.</p><p>To learn more about the Google Docs editors, please visit our <a href="https://support.google.com/docs/?hl=en&p=error_help" target="_blank">help center</a>.</p><p><br><b>We're sorry for the inconvenience.</b><br><i>- The Google Docs Team</i></p></div></div></body><style nonce="SNZIuIYhKP-y-W6MOr10TA">html {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}#outerContainer {margin: auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position: relative;}</style></html>
```

I tried to copy the file, but the same error was reproduced for the copy as well

Comment: how are you getting an export link exactly?  You need to download it using the api.

Comment: Yes, I get it with google drive SDK
`File file = drive.files().get(fileId).setSupportsAllDrives(true).setFields("id, name, exportLinks").execute()`
and then
`file.getExportLinks().get("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")`

Comment: Thats not an export this is [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export)  please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I can't use file.export due to its limitation of the exported content - 10MB. I need to get the content of the bigger files.

Comment: Then I know of no way to export a file from a Google docs type. programmatically

Comment: have you considered that the issue is the size of the file?  if this is the only file you have an issue downloading

Comment: I can get the content of similar files with sizes bigger than 10MB by the export link. But not the content of this file. I try to understand what can be wrong with a file to return such an error.

Comment: Sounds like a bug and its probably not something we can solve on stackoverflow. it could be something in the file itself that wont let it export  you can try and report it as a bug but i dont think its anything google will have time to look at its a single file.  https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025   try resaving it and puting it up again.